# How to make nemo support compressing files by context menu?

Tags: linux, desktop-environment, cinnamon, compression, nemo

I use Cinnamon on ArchLinux and Nemo is it's default file manager. I've tried 3 GUI file archivers (`p7zip` with WxGTK, `peazip` & `file-roller`), but none of them add a "compress option" in the context menu.

How can I add a "compress option" to Nemo's right click context menu?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### custom nemo action

This ArchLinux wiki article titled: [Nemo](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Nemo) describes the steps required to create your own context menu item.

#### General steps

1. Create a .nemo_action file. The file has to have this extension! Here's an example virus scanner .nemo_action file:

   `clamscan.nemo_action:`

   ```
   [Nemo Action]
   Name=Clam Scan
   Comment=Clam Scan

   Exec=gnome-terminal -x sh -c "clamscan -r %F | less"

   Icon-Name=bug-buddy

   Selection=Any

   Extensions=dir;exe;dll;zip;gz;7z;rar;
   ```
2. Place the .nemo_action file in one of the following locations:

   - `$HOME/.local/share/nemo/actions/`
   - `/usr/share/nemo/actions/`

### nemo fileroller

On that same wiki page there is also mention of a extension to Nemo called [Nemo Fileroller](https://github.com/linuxmint/nemo-extensions/tree/master/nemo-fileroller). You might be able to install this extension instead of creating your own.